# position: fixed, bottom: 0 does not seem to work for ionic app

Tags: css

I am trying to put a button tab to act as a footer for my app, but it does not stay at the bottom of the screen.  I thought position:fixed, bottom:0 would make it stay at the bottom.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPbQNZ

I gave the class .tabs-btm:

```
.tabs-btm {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: The CSS is fine, the problem is the order things are included in your codepen. The ionic CSS is included in the page after your CSS, so the ionic tabs CSS positioning overrides your fixed positioning.

Comment: You should include the whole necessary code related to the question inside your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Working solution:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXXJBp

Just changed your `tabs` div to outside of your `ion-content` element. That makes it stay on the first level after the `body` tag and be correctly affected by the `position:fixed;` rule.

Comment: You should include the whole necessary code related to the answer inside your post.

Comment: I considered that, but it was kind of difficult to demonstrate the purpose of my change by posting code. The change was in the placement of a snippet, and to show it I would have had to paste the whole thing again, which seemed unelegant...